# Right aligned italic letter get cut off partially in mat-form-filed angular

Tags: css, input, angular-material, right-align, mat-form-field

I have some mat-form-field, the data of that field is right aligned and it's font style will set dynamically. if we set the font-style italic the last letter get cut off partially. [image: cut off image] [image: cut off]

```
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" class="right">
      <input class="dynamic-style" matInput />
    </mat-form-field>

.right{
  text-align: right;
}
.dynamic-style{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Tried adding padding-right: 10px for the input tag. it is not working. Can any one please help in this?

Comment: I can't see this problem with vanilla HTML input element and vanilla CSS. Can you show us what the compiled code is (ie the actual HTML/CSS)?

Comment: I am using material-angular framework. it is actual html and css @AHaworth